# Visual Studio Code debugger for ASP.NET Core 2 don't work with different port

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

My intention is to start the VSCode debugger with different port than the default 5000 and for that I'm specifying the url both in "args" array (command-line args) and ASPNETCORE_URLS env variable. I'm using the following launch.json config for Visual Studio Code debugger:

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/MotelsBack.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/MotelsBack.API.dll",
            "args": ["urls=http://localhost:6000"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/MotelsBack.API",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
                //"ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:6000" --Commented, however this don't work also
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Debugger starts on the specified port showing this:

[debugger output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUCOV.png)

The debugger output says that the app can be reached through the url that I specified in both previous options, however when I visit this url from any explorer the app is not reached, it just don't work, but if I remove the port definition from launch.json to use the 5000 default port it works.

Visual Studio Code debugger doesn't accept a different port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Port 6000 is a port that is considered unsafe by browsers, so safari and chrome won't connect to them (WebKitErrorDomain:103 on on safari and ERR_UNSAFE_PORT on chrome).

Use a different, non-"unsafe", port for the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable and it should work.

Passing it via `--urls` is currently not possible in ASP.NET Core 2.0 but will be in 2.1 due to [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/issues/221) (see issue for a workaround).

Comment: Yeah it was my mistake using that unsafe port, I've changed to 5500 and now it works. For anyone that want to pass arguments via command-line, can use `var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build();` and use it within `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` passing it as parameter: `UseConfiguration(configuration)`.